# Could you please explain to me which answer is correct and why?

Tags: present-tense

She is really a good friend and she ........... to send me a letter each month .

( never failed / never fails )

Does " each " here refer to the present  simple or  the past simple ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never Fails is the correct answer over here.

**Reason:-**

It is a past continues sentence. That means that action is still being done to the present.
 In other words "she still doesn't fail to send me a letter"